# How do I react to a QML button click in C++

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am trying to launch a different QML Page from my C++ code by hooking into the clicked() slot of a button in my QML but it's not working.

```
    Button {
        objectName: btnLogin
        text: qsTr("Login")
        id: btnLogin
    }
```

And the c++

```
QObject *newButton = root->findChild<QObject*>("btnLogin");
QObject::connect(newButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(loginClick()));
```

The slots in my hpp file:

```
 public slots:  
    void loginClick();
```

And my clicked method:

```
void GConnectBB::loginClick() {
    int i = 0;

    Button *newButton = root->findChild<Button*>("btnLogin");
    if (newButton)
        newButton->setProperty("text", "New button text");
}


QObject *newButton = root->findChild<QObject*>("btnLogin");
```

Is null when I check through the debugger. I am extremely rusty with C++ and completely new to Qt, please be gentle :) What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't this considered a bad practice (access UI elements from c++)? I've been trying myself to learn how to connect my c++ object method to a qml object signal...

Comment: @JoaoMilasch yes it is. This was just an example. The primary goal was to get the C++ code to react to the button click.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should surround the object name with quotation marks:

```
Button {
    objectName: "btnLogin"
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: I guess this mistake comes from the fact that the id property doesn't have quotation marks.